# Fire jquery on width > 900

Tags: jquery, width

So, I'm trying to fire the following jquery actions only if the screen width is larger than 900px. Is the screen is smaller the .homepage should have the class .active.

```
$(function() {
    var header = $(".homepage");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 10) {
            header.addClass("active");
        } 
        else {
            header.removeClass("active");
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () { 
        $('.header-text').css({
            'top' : +($(this).scrollTop()/1)+"px"
        }); 
    });
});
```

Any help would be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**[WORKING FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8agqkpyu/)**

Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    checkWindow();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    checkWindow();
});

function checkWindow(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    console.log(windowWidth);
    if(windowWidth > 900){
        //do what you need to do when window > 900
    }
    else{
        // do what you need to do when window < 900
    }
}
```

If `$(window).width()` is not what you are looking for, you can also use `$(document).width()`.

```
// Returns width of browser viewport
$( window ).width();
// Returns width of HTML document
$( document ).width();
```

Comment: You may want to address the user re-sizing the window as well. You can simply wrap the above function in `$(window).resize(function(){   //your code here...});` Of course you'll need both functions, one inside the re-size event and one outside for checking when the window loads initially.

Comment: With this code, if the window is smaller than 900px, nothing will happen at all.

Comment: @Trucktech, I used the resize function, works great. Now i added it in a JSfiddle, for a better understanding. Hope the QA knows how to use it. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! And that is a great idea to put it in a function. You'll have to excuse me if I "borrow" that. Thanks!